# How to detect chrome "runtime.lastError: Serial connection not found"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, arduino, google-chrome-app

I built a chrome app to read serial data from Arduino. 
I am trying to catch **runtime.lastError: Serial connection not found** Error. 
Currently, I could not find any API call back to detect that error on chrome serial documentation.

This is how I am connecting to a port

```
Serial.connect("COM5", {bitrate: 9600}, onConnect);
```

My onConnect Function

```
const onConnect = function (connectionInfo) {
    if (connectionInfo) {
        connectionId = connectionInfo.connectionId;
    }
};
```

I need to send a message if the port is connected successfully. But I am unable to know if the connection is successful or not.

Comment: Try checking `chrome.runtime.lastError` inside onConnect function.

Comment: Yes, but it always shows error even when connected